# database in phone gap for blackberry

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cordova

I am using javascript for creating database in phonegap for blackBerry os4.6

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}


function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}



function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}


function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}
</script>
```

but am not getting it.Please tell me the solution how to do .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

use try-catch construction to intercept exceptions which may occur upon opening the database.

[Check this link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494756/Adding%20SQL%20Database%20support%20to%20your%20iPhone%20App)